# jQuery Validation: show one error msg for each error between 2 fileds

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

My requirement:

I use jQuery validation to validate form fields. there're several validation rules for 2 fields.

1. Show one error msg if the 2 fields have the same error.
2. Show each error if the 2 fields have different errors.

Problem:
I've tried using "groups", but it doesn't work for my requirement[2]. And the blur event makes the error result mass when u click another field.

I've tried "errorPlacement". I tried to check errors & hide one of the same error msg, but it doesn't work at last. you can refer to my code in "errorPlacement".

You can see my code here:

```js
$().ready(function() {
  // validate the comment form when it is submitted

  // validate signup form on keyup and submit
  $("#signupForm").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
      num: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        max: 88888
      },
      num2: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        max: 88888
      }
    },
    messages: {
      num1: {
        required: "Please enter num",
        minlength: "Your num must be at least 5 characters long"
      },
      num2: {
        required: "Please enter num",
        minlength: "Your num must be at least 5 characters long"
      }
    },
    groups: {
      num: "num num2"
    },

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      element.parent().append(error);

      var errAppend = "-error";
      var eleName = element.attr("name");
      var elSiblingsName = "";

      // error element
      var $ele01 = [];
      var $ele02 = [];

      // find $ele01 & $ele02
      var eleIndex = eleName.indexOf("2");
      if (eleIndex == -1) {
        $ele01 = $("#" + eleName + errAppend);
        $ele02 = $("#" + eleName + "2" + errAppend)
      } else {
        elSiblingsName = eleName.substr(0, eleName.length - 2);
        $ele01 = $("#" + elSiblingsName + errAppend);
        $ele02 = $("#" + eleName + errAppend);
      }

      // hide $ele02 if the text between $ele01 & $ele02 are the same
      // not null validation
      //if ($ele01.length != 0) {
      //  if ($ele02.length != 0) {
      //    // hide $ele02
      //    if ($ele01.text() == $ele02.text()) {
      //      $ele02.hide();
      //    }
      //  }
      //} else {
      //  if ($ele02.length != 0) {
      //    $ele02.show();
      //  } else {
      //    $ele02.hide();
      //  }
      //}

      if ($ele01.text()!="" && $ele02.text()!="") {
        if ($ele01.text() == $ele02.text()) {
          $ele02.hide();
        }
      }

      console.log(element.attr("name"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form action="" method="get" name="signupForm" id="signupForm">
  <div style="">
    <input type="text" name="num">
    <input type="text" name="num2">
    <input type="submit" id="validate" value="validate">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: there is a code snippet button in your post editor. for the lulz of it i've now edited your post and changed your fiddle into a snippet. its not visible before this edit has been reviewed though. just play around with all the buttons when asking your next question ;D

Comment: you can see the changes here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33264928/revisions on stackoverflow you are able to use markdown syntax in order to create lists and links. using the buttons will mostly insert such code pieces. some buttons also work on selected text.

Comment: @GottZ what is the use of creating the snippet that doesn't work similar to the one in fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/zgdx521/0bbLazth/20/) ?

Comment: sorry. i forgot to add the dependencies. it should be visible soon.

Comment: @GottZ, thanks for your edit~